# "Discrimination" due to COVID-19 Certificate requirements

Tags: european-union, discrimination, covid-19, switzerland

Many European countries issue COVID-19 Certificates (with varying names), that indicate whether a person is vaccinated, has recovered or has been tested. Access to some locations (restaurants, cinemas, discos, etc - varies by country) is only allowed if you present such a proof. Now people that don't want to get vaccinated call this discrimination, because they need to get tested very often to keep the right to visit those locations (as a test is only valid 48 to 72 hours, while a vaccination is currently valid a year).

But can this really be called "Discrimination"? I thought that the term was defined for a fact that one cannot change or has been given by birth (such as color of skin, sex, origin or religion). Except for a small minority which cannot be vaccinated for medical reasons, everyone has the ability to change one's vaccination status. (This seems to be backed by https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskriminierung)

Comment: Not a discrimination is *unlawful* discrimination

Comment: Not even among the things that one cannot change, not all discrimination is illegal. There are minimum age requirements for driving, drinking, voting, working and being ellected, among others.

Comment: Most countries have laws to prevent the spreading of [Communicable Diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contagious_disease). Therefore laws exist to prevent such spreading. Those who exercise their **right** not to be vaccinated are not exempted from these laws. The test requirement for those who exercise their **right** is a consequence of their own action. Since it is their own choice, it cannot be considered a discrimination.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*Since it is their own choice, it cannot be considered a discrimination.*" By that token, a bias for or against people on grounds of religion cannot be considered *unlawful* insofar as it is people's own choice to retain or switch religions.

Comment: @IñakiViggers That is a different problem. What is considered to be a higher rated right: **sex equality** or **freedom of religion**?

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*That is a different problem.*" It's not. Other than forced conversions throughout history, every year thousands (if not millions) of people *deliberately* leave their former religion because they no longer identify with its precepts. It is their own choice, yet they might experience unlawful discrimination. "*What is considered to be a higher rated right: **sex equality** or **freedom of religion**?*" That is quite an open-ended, complex, subjective matter that does not even relate to the OP's question. My point is that the rationale in your previous comment does not hold water.

Comment: @IñakiViggers You were the one that introduce another topic that has nothing to do with this question. In this topic **each** person must prove that they are not a carrier of a contagious disease. They can do so by providing proof of full **vaccination**, of **recovery** or have been **tested**. The choice of which is based their circumstances. That is not discrimination.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*You were the one that introduce another topic that has nothing to do with this question.*" I brought it up only as an example of why your rationale about "*their own choice*" is unavailing, not to improvise here a ranking of protected categories. The rest of your argument altogether misses the coercion inherent to having to pay tests, to have oneself pinched deep inside the nose, and to endure other vexations only for a person's choice not to get injected with the vaccine.

Comment: Religion is a difficult topic. Even if you do have the free choice to change it, at least according to the state law, this might not even save you from discrimination. Jews were and are discriminated just because they're born Jews, regardless of whether they practice their religion. Same with origin: Strangers are discriminated, even if they meanwhile have their new home's citizenship.

Comment: @PMF "*Jews were and are discriminated just because they're born Jews, regardless of whether they practice their religion.*" I hear you, but I think you are missing the point. My refutation is that the protection of a person's rights is not stricken merely on grounds that the matter involves the person's own choice(s).

Comment: "This seems to be backed by Wikipedia": the page you linked explicitly lists "political or other opinions" - and the German basic law [constitution] explicitly lists political opinion and philosophical creed as protected. These are both better examples for changeable since a religious person may say that their belief is something that comes to them from their god and therefore it is nothing they can change. And btw, disability is protected regardless whether it results from deliberate self-harm or not.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX As laid out below, not all political opinions are protected equaly. In view of the constitution, this does sound odd, but is considered a necessary requirement to keep public peace. One may not publicly express far-right ideologies in germany, despite freedom of speech.

Comment: @PMF: I guess you refer to §130 (4) StGB? That is *far* narrower: "Weder verbietet er [§130 (4) StGB] generell eine zustimmende Bewertung von Maßnahmen des nationalsozialistischen Regimes, noch ein positive Anknüpfung an Tage, Orte oder Formen, denen ein an diese Zeit erinnernder Sinngehalt mit gewichtiger Symbolkraft zukommt. Seine Verwirklichung setzt vielmehr die Gutheißung des Nationalsozialismus als historisch real gewordene Gewalt- und Willkürherrschaft voraus." source: https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Pressemitteilungen/DE/2009/bvg09-129.html ...

Comment: ... and that press release of the constitutional court also makes clear that this is a very special exception ("als nichtallgemeines Gesetz [...] ausnahmsweise vereinbar") due to the particular historical relevance, but also that that law does *not* prohibit opinios that belong to Nazi ideology as an opinion in itself "Diese Ausnahme nimmt die Meinungsfreiheit indes nicht auch inhaltlich zurück. [...] Das Ziel, Äußerungen wegen ihrer Unvereinbarkeit mit sozialen oder ethischen Auffassungen zu behindern, hebt das Prinzip der Meinungsfreiheit selbst auf und ist illegitim."

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I didn't say the opinion is forbidden (you can't really change that, anyway), I said it is illegal to publicly distribute that opinion according §130 (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It’s discrimination

Discrimination happens whenever a decision is made that favours one person or group and disfavours another person or group.

For example, as I write the Olympics are drawing to a close. These clearly discriminate against people who are not good at sport.

However, I think you may be confusing “discrimination” with the much narrower class of “unlawful discrimination”. Simply put, discrimination is lawful unless there is a law that says it isn’t.

### Unlawful Discrimination

Focussing on [Swiss](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/en) law, Article 8of the Constitution says:

> No person may be discriminated against, in particular on grounds of origin, race, gender, age, language, social position, way of life, religious, ideological, or political convictions, or because of a physical, mental or psychological disability.

An argument could be made that a decision not to get vaccinated or tested was a “way of life”, an “ideological conviction” or, from my point of view, a “psychological disability”. As such, a law that discriminated against such people would be unconstitutional.

Except, Article 36 says:

> Restrictions on fundamental rights must have a legal basis. Significant restrictions must have their basis in a federal act. The foregoing does not apply in cases of serious and immediate danger where no other course of action is possible.
>
> Restrictions on fundamental rights must be justified in the public interest or for the protection of the fundamental rights of others.
>
> Any restrictions on fundamental rights must be proportionate.
>
> The essence of fundamental rights is sacrosanct.

So, if there is a Federal law mandating vaccine passports and if the government can show that the restriction is “justified” and “proportionate” (which they have a decent shot at) such a law is constitutional.

Comment: Just to add to that, it's basically the same in Germany. [Basic Law art. 3(3)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0026) ([Art. 3 Nr. 3 GG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/art_3.html)), for private law we have the [General Act on Equal Treatment](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/index.html) (Allgemeines Gleichbehandlungsgesetz, [AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/agg/index.html)). The law itself is very similar to Swiss law.

Answer (score 4):

"Discrimination" is in some way treating people differently from other people. Much discrimination is a sound idea. Not letting someone fly a plane who does not have pilot training  is discrimination, but not a bad kind. So is not allowing someone to do surgery who has not trained as a doctor.

***Unlawful discrimination*** is discrimination that a particular law in a particular country declares to be forbidden. Different countries have different laws for what kinds of discrimination is unlawful under what circumstances.

Discrimination on a basis not forbidden by law  is legal, even if immoral. For example, a restaurant could, in most if not all countries, ban left-handed people from being served there. This might be immoral, but would not be illegal, because no law has made it illegal.

Commonly, discrimination on the basis of religion, ethnicity, national origin, sex, or political opinion is unlawful. In some jurisdictions discrimination on the basis of disability is unlawful. Other bases may be unlawful in some places. There may be exceptions. Employment discrimination may not have the same standards as housing discrimination, and admission to public places or ability to run for public office may be different yet. All this will vary based on the particular laws of particular places.

Note that some of these protected classes are things about which people have no choice, such as sex and national origin, others are matters of choice such as religion and political opinion. Laws may create a protected class on any basis. Note also that many things about which people have little or no choice, such as height, handedness, or intelligence, are not protected categories in most places.

To the best of my understanding being vaccinated or not is not a ***protected class*** in most if not all of Europe, so legal distinctions may be made based on vaccination status. In such jurisdictions, discrimination in favor of those who are vaccinated is legal, although some may think it wrong.

A few US states have made it unlawful to restrict various public or private services or access to places on the basis of vaccination status. I am not aware of any country in Europe that has such a law.

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, the discrimination applied to people who desire a pilot's license is also desirable, for the most part.  Certain physical conditions that are forbidden grounds of discrimination in certain contexts are allowed, for example, such as blindness, deafness, and poor cardiovascular health.

Comment: As another matter, the authority to make laws and regulations protecting public health can probably trump anti-discrimination law, at least in the EU.  If there were a communicable disease that could only be spread by men, it would probably be permissible to impose quarantine regulations that discriminate on the basis of sex.

Comment: @phoog only to the extent that those laws and regulations did not infringe Constitutional rights.

Comment: @DaleM that's a bit of question begging.  My assertion is that the laws and regulations are permissible because of the state interest in protecting public health.  Where that interest trumps constitutional rights, it may restrict those rights without infringement.  This is how quarantines work, which restrict individual liberty despite its being a constitutional right.

Comment: @phoog sure, but the government would have to prove that was the case and the Constitution or case law of the specific country would have to allow the point of law that compelling interest trips the specific right. Bills of rights in European countries are more sacrosanct then the are in Anglophone ones: they remember living under the Nazis.

Comment: @DaleM as an American who's lived in Europe, I found the opposite: for the very reason you cite, European rights of expression are _less_ sacrosanct.  Governments there are quicker to restrict expressions of Nazi ideas and symbols than is the US.  A burka ban would never fly in the US.  Similarly, the explicit exceptions in EU free movement law for concerns of public safety, policy, and (most relevant here) health recognize that common needs sometimes outweigh individual rights.

Comment: That's definitely true. There are laws (such as the Art 261bis of the Swiss Criminal Code) that explicitly restrict freedom of speech in favor of public peace.

Comment: "ban left-handed people" - A restaurant banning left-handed people would be acting stupid. People often think because something is stupid it must be illegal.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes it would be unwise, but it would be legal. Many foolish things are legal. My point is that discrimination that is not because of a protected class is legal, whether it is wise or not.

Comment: @DaleM "only to the extent that those laws and regulations did not infringe Constitutional rights" - that in turn only applies in countries which have a constitution which takes precedence over ordinary statute.

Comment: "To the best of my understanding being vaccinated or not is not a protected class in most if not all of Europe" - true, but it could almost certainly be argued that it falls within a protected class in cases where being vaccinated goes against a person's religion or belief. In such a case any lawfulness would be based on an exception rather than the lack of protected characteristic.

Comment: @gnasher729, David Siegel: if restaurants started discriminating against lefties, I don't suppose it would be very long before handedness were added to the list of protected characteristics.

Comment: @phoog note they did not say "freedom of expression" but rather "bills of rights". Given the choice between having freedom to be a Nazi, or having freedom to not have other people be Nazis, the second option is obviously better for society (unless you were a Nazi, which would be your own ill-advised choice and you'd be welcome to change it).

Comment: @user253751 what is the point of stressing "bills of rights" over "freedom of expression"?  The latter is merely one of several rights typically included in bills of rights.  And no bill if rights includes a right not to have other people be Nazis or to follow any particular ideology.

Comment: @phoog Exactly, it's merely one of several rights. You can't refute "they have stronger rights" by saying "they have weaker freedom of expression" because that's just one right out of many.

Comment: @user253751 the assertion isn't that anyone has stronger rights but that bills of rights are more sacrosanct in Europe than in the US.  The example of freedom of expression arose because the reason given for this supposed state of affairs is that Europeans remember living under the Nazis.  But there are other examples of rights that support the idea that European countries actually take a far more pragmatic and flexible approach to guaranteeing rights than does the US; recent public health measures are another.

Answer (score 0):

> can this really be called "Discrimination"?

In many EU countries it would constitute unlawful discrimination because it directly translates to penalizing a person for deciding not to get vaccinated.

It is important to clarify that not everywhere is the concept of *unlawful discrimination* limited to categories such as the ones you list ("*color of skin, sex, origin or religion*"). For instance, the Constitutions of [Germany](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/GG.pdf) (art. "*Freiheit des Glaubens, des Gewissens [...] und weltanschaulichen Bekenntnises*"), [Spain](https://www.boe.es/legislacion/documentos/ConstitucionCASTELLANO.pdf) (art. 14, "*opinión*"), and [Switzerland](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/de) (art. 8 "*weltanschaulichen oder politischen Überzeugung*") protect a person's convictions/beliefs or ideology besides religious ones.

Requiring a Covid-19 certificate is discriminatory insofar as it imposes on "anti-vaxxers" significant costs and vexations as a condition for access to services, locations, and arguably even to fundamental rights. The cost of each test is equivalent to paying recurrent fines for not getting vaccinated, yet that is not the only penalization. Adapting one's schedule to take the test (perhaps also for retrieving the results), enduring the physical unpleasantness that these invasive tests entail, risking the implications of getting a false positive, and being subjected the disproportionate constraints on asymptomatic positives are devised inconveniences with which the governments intentionally react to anti-vaxxers' holding of their position.

Mainstream arguments such as that about [consequences of one's choices and preventing contagions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/70537/discrimination-due-to-covid-19-certificate-requirements#comment146886_70537) can be debunked with a religion-based analogy:

Demanding a Covid certificate as a condition for visiting a location is equivalent to requiring most of non-Christians to convert to Christianity (i.e., get vaccinated) or alternatively get a costly police certificate (i.e., Covid test) that is valid for 48 to 72 hours so as to ensure that those people are not al-Qaeda terrorists (i.e., not be carriers of a contagious disease). It is mistaken for someone to allege that these vexations, constraints, and undue pressure are lawful on grounds that deciding not to convert to Christianity (i.e., not to get vaccinated) is the individuals' *own choice*.

The Constitutions admittedly give governments the authority to enact laws and adopt measures to fight or prevent the spread of severe diseases. Two examples are art. 118 and art. 74(1)19 of the Switzerland and Germany Constitution, respectively. However, reading into these provisions a "lawfulness" of the coercion, undue pressure, and barriers against anti-vaxxers is premature and disproportionate, more so on a matter that is plagued with gaps and inconsistencies among the mainstream media. In fact, item 7.3.1 of [Resolution 2361 of the Parliamentary Assembly](https://pace.coe.int/en/files/29004/html) urges Member states to "*ensure that citizens are informed that the vaccination is not mandatory and that no one is under political, **social or other pressure** to be vaccinated if they do not wish to do so*" (emphasis added). See also item 7.3.2 ("*ensure that no one is discriminated against for not having been vaccinated, due to possible health risks or not wanting to be vaccinated*").

Comment: I do not think that the analogy between carrying a disease and holding certain religious views is valid, useful or persuasive. While various EU country laws prohibit discrimination against those who hold a particular belief, that does not mean that all actions taken in support of or because of that belief are protected. I would like to see specific cites to cases or occasions when .restrictions on unvaccinated people or other restrictions to control disease, have been held unlawful discrimination. I doubt that laws in Europe would be  or have been interpreted in such a way.

Comment: The Christianity argument is inapt: conversion is a public affirmation of faith, and mandatory conversion is directly against freedom of belief.  But mandatory vaccination does not require the patient to change what they think about vaccines, nor to make any statements of belief that are contrary to their conscience.  A closer analogy might be a requirement to undergo a security screening to enter a stadium.  Does it discriminate against those whose conscience dictates that they must carry a dangerous weapon at all times?  Yes.  Is that discrimination illegal?  No.

Comment: Mandatory vaccination does require some people to submit to something they disagree with, but the same is true of other government mandates, including taxation and traffic regulations.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*I would like to see specific cites to cases or occasions when .restrictions on unvaccinated people or other restrictions to control disease, have been held unlawful discrimination.*" See item 7.3.1 of [Resolution 2361 of the Parliamentary Assembly](https://pace.coe.int/en/files/29004/html) (urging Member states to "*ensure that citizens are informed that the vaccination is not mandatory and that no one is under political, social or other pressure to be vaccinated if they do not wish to do so*").

Comment: @Iñaki Viggers that is a resolution from the Council of Europe, which is not a legislative body. It **urges** member states and the EU to notify all that vaccination is not mandatory and to ensure that no one is discriminated against for not being vaccinated. this is not a law, court decision or other legally binding rule that such discrimination is unlawful. It is merely advocacy.

Comment: @DavidSiegel in addition to that, the idea that a member state can meaningfully "ensure that citizens are informed ... that no one is under ... social ... pressure to be vaccinated" is frankly ludicrous.  I mean, you can tell them that, but doing so has no effect on the social pressure that they actually do or don't experience.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128357/discussion-on-answer-by-inaki-viggers-discrimination-due-to-covid-19-certifica).